# Sending httpOnly cookie also in HTTP response body

Tags: web-application, cookies, session-management

I've done some researches on this topic, and I found this question on SE:
[Sending session cookie inside the HTTP response body](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137884/sending-session-cookie-inside-the-http-response-body)

But this answered my question just in part.

On login, my server will create a httpOnly cookie, and also put this authorization token in the response body. This is because my server handles normal HTTP requests from a browser, and also provides RESTful APIs.

In case of an API request, the client will then find the token in the response body and use it accordingly. *(I believe that the cookie won't be received because the request is not made through a normal browser, correct me if I am wrong.)*

In case of a browser request, the token will be received as a httpOnly cookie, but also in the response body. My doubt is: wouldn't this just nullify the fact of using an httpOnly cookie, since I'm also sending the token in the response body?

The problem arises because I need to handle also API calls, which is why I send the token in the response body.

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to send the token in the request body, it must be stored somewhere script-accessible (probably in session or local storage). If it's stored somewhere script-accessible, then there is literally no point having the cookie be HttpOnly.

HttpOnly is only barely a security measure to begin with - for most exploitation scenarios, it might limit the damage or make exploitation harder, but XSS can still easily be catastrophic for the user - and it only makes sense at all if the cookie value is never exposed to script anywhere else. Since that doesn't apply here, the HttpOnly flag is pointless.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It confirms my doubts. At this point, I would ask how to implement it in a secure way, but still being able to handle browser requests and provide RESTful APIs.

Comment: Maybe sending the token not in the response body but in another way (authorization header?) would solve it.

Comment: @Kenna Go ahead and ask a new question if you haven't already, but the short answer is that, from a security perspective, sending the token in the body or in a header are both fine. Neither will be leaked to an adversary, both prove that the caller has the secret, neither is vulnerable to CSRF, etc. The only difference I can think of is that using the header with legitimate cross-origin XHR/fetch requires a slightly more complicated CORS configuration, but that's not a security issue.

Comment: Ok, if I won't find enough data on my question, I will ask a new question on this subject. I really appreciate your help.